# How to install mysql server 5.6 on ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 system?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, installation, ubuntu

What are the steps to install MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 system?

I know that MySQL 5.6 version is not available in 18.04 and 20.04 apt repos. Any other way to install this particular version?

Comment: May I ask, **why, exactly** you want to do this? MySQL now has CHECK constraints, CTEs and window functions - all goodies you do **not** want to miss!

Comment: Are you serious, @Vérace? Are you under the impression that all production database servers are running the latest version of the database software, or that MySQL's new versions are backwards-compatible with old data?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way to install mysql 5.6 on ubuntu 18.04 / 20.04. We can install it via deb https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-debian.html

Answer (score 1):

Answers left in comments:

If you are comfortable with Docker, that would be the fastest solution. You can spin up a container with MySQL 5.6 quite easily and not have to worry that an OS update will b0rk the SQL installation. - [matigo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/228577/matigo)

MySQL 5.6 is outdated and not longer supported. So you should think about if 5.7 or MariaDB would work for you as their are compatible in most cases. - [nbk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/190821/nbk)

You could use a source code install - it's quite easy if you **carefully** follow the instructions. - [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race)